# Checking if mysql query provides the best solution to the question

Tags: mysql, relational-database

> List the Employee names and address of all the employees working in
>   the EmployeeType whose code is 1 and the hourly rate of pay is €40.

I would like to know if this is the best way of retrieving information from the question above

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName , e.EmployeeAddress
FROM Employee e JOIN EmployeeType et ON e.EmployeeType = et.EmployeeType
HAVING e.EmployeeCode = (1) AND et.TotalPay = (40);
```

Comment: its not haveing, its HAVING

Comment: Opps typo, does it look ok apart form that(edited)?

Comment: `HAVING ...` is wrong: only use `HAVING` after a `GROUP BY`. Instead put `WHERE ...`, as does @Zeljka's answer. There are many ways to write this query; probably they are equally efficient (if your SQL engine is smart). Asking for the 'best solution' would need a value judgment: what criteria for 'best'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use 'HAVING' in this query, I would prefer WHERE condition or add more parameters on join. You can read about HAVING on this [LINK](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)
Having is little bit different then WHERE condition, because its applied after querying results.

1st solution with simple WHERE condition

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName , e.EmployeeAddress
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN EmployeeType et ON e.EmployeeType = et.EmployeeType
WHERE e.EmployeeCode = '1' AND et.TotalPay = '40';
```

2nd solution add more parameters on join

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName , e.EmployeeAddress
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN EmployeeType et ON (e.EmployeeType = et.EmployeeType AND et.TotalPay = '40')
WHERE e.EmployeeCode = '1' ;
```

Comment: The 1st solution's `JOIN` is `ON` same-named columns. So you could use `NATURAL JOIN`. But that might go wrong if there are other same-named columns between the two tables. @Liam's q should state the full schema for the tables.